# bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory when installing lunarvim on my ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: 20.04

So I tried to run: `sudo bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lunarvim/lunarvim/master/utils/installer/install.sh)` in order to install `lunarvim` however I get :`bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`

Comment: The page you are trying to download is 404

Answer (score 0):

Well,I found a solution to my problem,it turns out all what you need to do is use fnm(an npm manager) here is the github link:https://github.com/Schniz/fnm,it saves the overhead of dealing with permission issues with npm(when installing lunarvim use "bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lunarvim/lunarvim/master/utils/installer/install.sh)" without sudo)
Hopes this helps anyone who's gonna run into such a problem in the future